# Find record by 2 parameters which one is an array

Tags: sql, doctrine, dql

i have table Collection:

```
id  orderId   productId
1     201        1
2     202        2
3     205        3
4     206        1
5     207        1
6     208        1
7     311        2
```

OrderId and ProductId is relations to Collection table.
And I need to check if exist record where eg. productId = 1 AND orderId[205, 206, 207, 208].

How i should built my query to find what i want?

The array of orderId is not static, it's dynamic and depends of situation, can have diffrent number of elements. I tried to make it like this:

```
$ordersCollection = [various id objects of orders ];
$productId = just productId

createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->andWhere('p.product = :productId')
        ->andWhere('p.order in :ordersCollection')
        ->setParameters(['productId' => $productId, 'ordersCollection' => $ordersCollection])
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

try like below by using exists

```
select t1.* table t1
where t1.productId=1
and exists( select 1 from table t2 where t1.productId=t2.productId
                 and orderId in(205, 206, 207, 208)
                   having count( distinct orderId)=4
          )
```

Comment: Thank you for response but it don't work when i 'translated' it to DQL query. I edited my post to add more details

Answer (score 0):

EDIT. Ok, i forgot to add bracket in

```
->andWhere('p.order in :ordersCollection')
```

it should be

```
->andWhere('p.order in (:ordersCollection)')
```